# Confirming requests

Tags: jsp

I have to create a program where a member of staff requests to change a module. This is then sent to the head staff which they can validate the request however I have no idea how to do it. I have been using jsp and html to do it but havent been able to do it. Help

Comment: What exactly have you tried? What does "requests to change a module" mean? Shouldn't a simple mail form be okay where the head staff can respond and forward the message to the appropriate people?

Comment: From example lets say that a member of staff wants to delete a module then they will send a request on what module they want to delete by entering the module code. This should then be sent to the head staff who deletes it.